# Is it considered bad practice to write db queries in a controller rather than a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've read that best practice dictates fats models, skinny controllers.

Models should contain business logic such as getting a list of customers based on parameters sent from a controller.

Controllers should contain just enough logic to invoke methods within a model to return to a view.

However I see many examples and tutorials where there is logic within the controller such as a query that accesses a db to get a list of products. I was under the impression that the logic should live in a method inside a model. The controller can then invoke this method, rather than containing the actual logic to query the database.

So if I have a `ProductController` I might have a Index action which returns an Index View, and I would have a `ProductModel` which would house my logic to display certain products based on a query string(which the `ProductController` would pass to said model). Right?

Comment: As long as your application adheres to a formal architecture (not random code everywhere it fits) and you follow it strictly as you can and you also test and make sure you aren't over-engineering and cause lots of overhead/issues etc - then you are free to implement any software design you really want, that's the beauty of programming. Remember it was just some muppet like any of us that thought up the MVC paradigm - Just please make sure you don't end up with a dailywtf.com website :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So if I have a ProductController I might have a Index action which returns an Index View, and I would have a ProductModel which would house my logic to display certain products based on a query string(which the ProductController would pass to said model). Right?

That is correct. As per the [Model-view-controller architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

> The **model** manages the behavior and data of the application domain,
>   responds to requests for information about its state (usually from the
>   view), and responds to instructions to change state (usually from the
>   controller). In event-driven systems, the model notifies observers
>   (usually views) when the information changes so that they can react.
>
> The **view** renders the model into a form suitable for interaction,
>   typically a user interface element. Multiple views can exist for a
>   single model for different purposes. A viewport typically has a one to
>   one correspondence with a display surface and knows how to render to
>   it.
>
> The **controller** receives user input and initiates a response by making
>   calls on model objects. A controller accepts input from the user and
>   instructs the model and viewport to perform actions based on that
>   input.

Keep the data-related queries and operations in the model; stuff as much as you can in there in accordance with DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Make the functions reusable as much as possible so they can be ported into various controllers and used throughout the application as necessary.

The view should contain little - if any - logic outside of view-specific work.

Your controller functions should invoke the model functions required to retrieve and manipulate data, and should be as "thin" as possible (as you pointed out). The smaller and less involved the controller, the easier it will be to add asynchronous features that "don't reboot the application" on the front-end, making for a better user experience. (If you are concerned about this, anyway!)

Comment: thanks for that explanation, I was becoming unconfident in which practice was correct. Also, is it best to have the controller invoke the model then pass that data to the view, or can I simply add a reference to the model within the view and access the returned data from the view?

Comment: The model gets instructions from a controller in most typical deployments, so you would have the view asynchronously communicate with a controller that returned data, perhaps in XML or JSON format. The controller would interface with the model(s), and format the data properly for delivery to the view. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score -4):

The *Add Controller* dialog box in VS 2010 has the option of adding a scaffold with CRUD functions into the controller. This should tell you quite a bit above how the ASP.NET MVC dev. team views this debate.

Comment: I guess since ORM's and LINQ make querying so effortless it's not a problem if you have to repeat some of the same queries. I think i'll mimic how the template is setup.

Comment: I guess there a some folks that would disagree with this... ;)